# Global 24-hour time format in KDE Plasma

Tags: 20.04, kde

I am using **KDE Plasma 5.18.5** in **Ubuntu 20.04**. Plasma by default came with 12-hour time format and it is displayed everywhere-- from the digital clock widget to the lock screen. But I prefer to use the 24-hour format.

However, I cannot understand how to change the time format globally to 24-hour. I have looked into many places in the System Settings, but there was no sign of that setting. I have searched thoroughly under the **Regional Settings** page, but still haven't found any such thing.

How to change the time format globally to 24-hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In KDE, go over to the clock on your bottom taskbar and right-click it.
Once done there is a coniguration icon.

[image]

Once done click on the Time-Display option and then you can change the time-format to either 12-hour or 24-hour.
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 4):

In **KDE 5.22.4** (Find your version in the About program):

Right click the time > Configure Digital Clock > Time Display > 24-hour